# Physical volume for RAID missing in Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, hp-proliant, hpe

I am trying to configure software RAID 1 on ubuntu 16.04.4, but the option “physical volume for RAID” is missing during the disk partitioning process.. Does anyone have a solution for that issue? 
Noting that the server that we are using is HP Proliant DL380 Gen 10 and the the raid controller is S100i
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The HPE Smart Array S100i software RAID controller is a Windows-only controller which is not supported in Linux. To run Linux, you will need to replace it with another Smart Array controller. The [HPE Smart Array Gen10 Controllers Data Sheet](https://cc.cnetcontent.com/vcs/hp-ent/inline-content/SI/C/6/C618AE536CBF24EB5D084B8EA92A104D796CEA9D_source.PDF) shows which controllers are supported in Linux -- which is literally every other controller but that one.